# How to remove all query string and extension pages to the modified versions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)$ authors.php?current_page=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ books.php?tag=$1&current_page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Books-single/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ book-single.php?tag=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Books-by/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ book-by.php?auth=$1&current_page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^authors-by/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ authors-by.php?author-by=$1&current_page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

when i type in the  dunamic url the address bar like localhost:/somefolder/books.php?tag=Love-Books&page=2 this url still works, I wanted all the url with queries to redirect to its static version url.

Comment: So what's the problem? (and "doesn't work" tells us absolutely nothing)

Comment: The problem is that when i type in the query/string in the url like http://localhost:/somefolder/books.php?tag=Love-Books&page=2 this url still works, I wanted all the url with queries to redirect to its static url.